# Current through a metallic conductor

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance

When battery is not connected to conductor why there is 
no heating effect while electrons are having very high kinetic energy? 
I want to know what happen in such a case 
What would be the resistance?

Answer (score 0):

The system is in thermal equilibrium. There is no net transfer of energy between the electrons and the lattice. Any heat the electrons a give off is returned by the phonons, and vice versa.